# Control the value of jquery bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check the value of a progress bar in jQuery?
Lets say that I push a button and it goes to 50% and if I push the button of 25% i would like to get an alert which says "You cant go under 50%"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../test/pics/bbti.png" />
  <title>Bing Bang Theory</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../test/css/style2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>bbt</h1>
  <!--progress bar start-->
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
  <br />
  <button onclick="set25()">Set to 25%</button>

  <button onclick="set50()">Set to 50%</button>

  <button onclick="set75()">Set to 75%</button>

  <button onclick="set100()">Set to 100%</button>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: 0
      });
    });
    // Set progressbar to 25%
    function set25() {
      //somewhere here is the code about if statement. 
      $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", 25);
    }
    // Set progressbar to 50%
    function set50() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", 50);
    }
    // Set progressbar to 75%
    function set75() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", 75);
    }
    // Set progressbar to 100%
    function set100() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", 100);
    }
  </script>
  <!--progress bar stops-->

</body>

</html>
```

Can you help me solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one single function to perform the operations. And you can avoid inline JS which can be a nightmare to maintain.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
    $('button[data-value]').on('click',function() {
        var pbar = $('#progressbar'),
            value = $(this).data('value'),
            curValue = pbar.progressbar('value');
        if( value < curValue ) {
            alert("You can't go under " + curValue +"%!");
        } else {
            pbar.progressbar( 'value', value );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<br />
<button data-value="25">Set to 25%</button>
<button data-value="50">Set to 50%</button>
<button data-value="75">Set to 75%</button>
<button data-value="100">Set to 100%</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple functions like set25, set50 ... have a single function and send values to it. Something like this

```
function set(progressBarValue){}
```

And call it like this

```
<button onclick="set(25)">Set to 25%</button>
<button onclick="set(50)">Set to 50%</button>
<button onclick="set(75)">Set to 75%</button>
<button onclick="set(100)">Set to 100%</button>
```

In order to get the current value of a progress bar you can do this

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
```

Overall it should look something like this

```
var myprogressbar;
$(document).ready(function () {
    myprogressbar = $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
});

function set(val) {
    var currVal = myprogressbar.progressbar("option", "value");
    if(currVal > val){
        alert('Cannot go lower');
        return;
    }
    myprogressbar.progressbar("option", "value", val);
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/NAs3V/381/**